# Parsing NLTK Chart diagram

Tags: python, nlp, treeview, nltk, text-parsing

I am trying to do parsing using context free grammar which is returning multiple parse trees.
I can visualize these parse trees one by one using the code below:

```
grammar = nltk.CFG.fromstring("""
  S   -> VP NP PUN | NP VP PUN | NP PUN | VP PUN
  NP  -> ADP NP | NOUN | ADJ NP | ADV ADJ NP |ADJ | CONJ NP | NOUN NP | DET NP |ADV
  VP  -> VERB | ADV VP | ADV | VERB VP | VERB NP
  
  ADP -> 'as' | 'in' | 'along' | 'with' | 'of' | 'a'
  NOUN ->  'three' | 'parts' | 'milk' | 'oak' | 'body' | 'center' | 'stage' | 'notes' | 'date' | 'rice' | 'structure' | 'a' | 'hint' | 'blossom' | 'candy' | 'chocolate' | 'lemon' | 'thyme' | 'espresso' | 'cacao' | 'tart' | 'honeysuckle' | 'citrus' | 'apricot' | 'finish' | 'paste' | 'grapefruit' | 'cherry' | 'mouthfeel' | 'spice' | 'cup' | 'vanilla' | 'narcissus' | 'savory-tart' | 'aroma' | 'leads' | 'zest' | 'herb' | 'florals' | 'tones' | 'peppercorn' | 'intimations' | 'nib'
  PUN -> '.' | ',' | ';' | '(' | ')'
  DET -> 'the' | 'all' | 'a'
  ADV -> 'as' | 'deeply' | 'long' | 'all' | 'gently' | 'crisply' | 'richly' | 'delicately' | 'sweetly' 
  VERB -> 'evaluated' | 'take' | 'notes' | 'follow' | 'roasted' | 'dried' | 'fruit' | 'finish' | 'drying' | 'leads' | 'intensify'
  X -> 'a'
  CONJ -> 'and'
  PRT -> 'in'
  ADJ -> 'rich' | 'dark' | 'black' | 'short' | 'small' | 'sweet' | 'white' | 'floral' | 'silky' | 'pink' | 'thyme-like' | 'syrupy' | 'roasted' | 'dried' | 'floral-toned' | 'chocolaty' | 'sweet-toned' | 'cocoa-toned' | 'plush' | 'floral-driven' | 'herb-toned' | 'delicate' | 'resonant' | 'flavor-saturated'
  """)

statement = nltk.word_tokenize("Crisply sweet cocoa-toned Lemon blossom roasted cacao nib date rice candy white peppercorn in aroma and cup.")
statement = [i.lower().strip() for i in statement]

rd_parser = nltk.RecursiveDescentParser(grammar)
for pos, tree in enumerate(rd_parser.parse(statement)):
    tree.draw()
```

But the problem is that it generates the tree diagram one by one and the program stops untill I stop all of the charts manually. Is there a way by which I can generate all the charts into single image and display it in my jupyter notebook all at once?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include `grammer` and `statement` (or a subset of them)?

Comment: @OriYarden, I have added the grammar and statement.

Comment: running your code I get the error 'no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable', and rd_parser.parse(statement) is a generator object.

Comment: I am not sure why. Cause it is running on my end.